# Arrow function doesn't work in 'change' and 'input' addEventListener

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, user-input, addeventlistener

I have a text input on form. Now, I wanna try to fetch the data from this input by using 'change' and 'input' event in JavaScript.

Now the HTML code is :

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="input">
</form>
```

And the Javacript code is :

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
   console.log(this.value);
})

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
   console.log(this.value);
})
```

I was expecting that, if an user makes some changes in the text input, the changed data will be showed in console. In that case, normal or anynomous function is working but arrow function doesn't.

Comment: Arrow functions do not bind their own `this`, In this case, `this` is a window object, so `this.value` will be `undefined`